# Using shell script to convert questions in a text file into JSON format

Tags: json, bash

I have a text file with contents:

```
//input.txt
1) What is the first month of the year?
a) March
b) February
c) January
d) December
Answer: c) January

2) What is the last month of the year?
a) July
b) December
c) August
d) May
Answer: b) December
```

I would like to write a shell script that loops through this file input.txt (which has many more contents with the same format) and produce an output similar to the below JSON

```
[
 {
  "question": "What is the first month of the year?",
  "a": "March",
  "b": "February",
  "c": "January",
  "d": "December",
  "answer": "January",
 },
 {
  "question": "What is the last month of the year?",
  "a": "July",
  "b": "December",
  "c": "August",
  "d": "May",
  "answer": "December",
 },
[
```

I started by trying to write a bash script, to loop through the file and put each line separated by an empty line into curly brackets, and each item in the curly brackets into quotation marks, and separated by a comma, but it isn't working

```
#!/bin/bash

output=""

while read line; do
  if [ -z "$line" ]; then
    output+="}\n"
  else
    output+="\"${line}\","
    if [ $(echo "$output" | tail -n 1) == "" ]; then
      output+="{"
    fi
  fi
done < input.txt

output+="}"

echo "$output" > output.txt
```

Comment: I would recommend you use a tool like `jq` for this. Constructing a json by hand is what we would call "a very bad idea"™️.

Comment: can  you use other tools? Not sure if `jq` can handle such tasks, but that is the sine-qa-none of json tools. Else `awk, python, perl` (in ascending order of up-take).  Good luck.

Comment: Honestly, doesn't sound too hard with just `jq` (and `grep`).

Comment: @cyqsimon : I'm sure  you're right. The couple of `jq` tutorials I went thru never processed input such as in this question. Post an answer and I'll up-vote it. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq -R -s '
sub("\n+$"; "") |
split("\n\n") | map(
  split("\n") | map(split(") ")) | [
    {question: .[0][1]},
    (.[1:-1][] | {(.[0]): .[1]}),
    {answer: .[-1][1]}
  ] | add
)' input.txt
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nM1m376JqJu)</sup>

Comment: @oguzismail It is; the OP just didn't know it :)

Comment: This works for me. I had no idea about these tools. I will take a look into then and learn how they work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

You will pull all your hair out trying to generate proper JSON with Bash.

First, your example JSON output is not proper JSON. The trailing `,` are not supported in arrays and mappings. So you example needs to be:

```
[{
        "question": "What is the first month of the year?",
        "a": "March",
        "b": "February",
        "c": "January",
        "d": "December",
        "answer": "January"
    },
    {
        "question": "What is the last month of the year?",
        "a": "July",
        "b": "December",
        "c": "August",
        "d": "May",
        "answer": "December"
    }
]
```

(Note no `,` after each `"answer"` or after the final `}`. You check for valid JSON with a tool or [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com))

To generate that from your input, there are many JSON generator tools. The easiest for ME is Ruby:

```
ruby -00 -r json -ne '
BEGIN{out=[]}
sub(/\A\d+\)\s+/,"question)")
sub(/Answer: [a-z]/,"answer")
out << $_.split(/\R/).map{|l| l.split(/[):]\s*/,2)}.to_h
END{puts JSON.pretty_generate(out)}' file
```

Prints:

```
[
  {
    "question": "What is the first month of the year?",
    "a": "March",
    "b": "February",
    "c": "January",
    "d": "December",
    "answer": "January"
  },
  {
    "question": "What is the last month of the year?",
    "a": "July",
    "b": "December",
    "c": "August",
    "d": "May",
    "answer": "December"
  }
]
```

Comment: Sorry, the wrong JSON format was a typo. Thank you this also works for me

Answer (score 1):

Two different approaches (with the same result) with the JSON-parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
$ xidel -s input.txt -e '
  array{
    for $x in tokenize($raw,"\n\n")
    let $a:=tokenize($x,"\n")
    return
    map:merge((
      {"question":substring-after($a[1],") ")},
      $a[position() = 2 to 5] ! {substring-before(.,")"):substring-after(.,") ")},
      {"answer":substring-after($a[6],") ")}
    ))
  }
'

$ xidel -s input.txt -e '
  array{
    for $x in tokenize($raw,"\n\n") return
    map:merge(
      for $y at $i in tokenize($x,"\n") return {
        if ($i eq 1) then "question"
        else if ($i eq 6) then "answer"
        else substring-before($y,")"):
        substring-after($y,") ")
      }
    )
  }
'
```